# variable assignment inside 'IF' condition

Tags: php, javascript

in php, something like this is fine:

```
<?php
    if ( !$my_epic_variable = my_epic_function() ){
        // my epic function returned false
        // my epic variable is false
        die( "false" );
    }

    echo $my_epic_variable;
?>
```

I suppose is a shorter way of doing:

```
$my_epic_variable = my_epic_function();
if ( !$my_epic_variable ){
        die( "false" );
}
```

Can this be done is javascript? I've tried to no success, wasnt sure if there was some kind of special syntax or something

Comment: Fyi, in such a case additional parentheses are a good idea to make the intention clear: `if((foo = bar()))`

Comment: It depends... What you are trying to achieve? JavaScript is pretty "unique" so for the best result please provide us more infos...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the same in JavaScript, with one key difference.
You cannot *declare* a (locally scoped) variable inside the if clause, you may only refer to it.

So, declare it first:

```
var someVar;
```

Then use it however you want:

```
if (!(someVar = someFunction())) { /* do some stuff */ }
```

Notice that you will also have to wrap negated expressions `(!(expression))` with parentheses

This however, will not work:

```
if (var someVar = someFunction()) { /* NOPE */ }
```

Comment: You can't declare a **local** variable inside the if clause, since it requires the `var` keyword. You can, however, declare a global variable (though, generally, it's a bad idea).

Comment: @AnthonyGrist good point -- updated my answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist the real issue here is that you are not using an expression anymore but a statement.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that works fine. However, if you're inversing (`!`), then you need to wrap the assignment in parentheses otherwise you'll get a syntax error.

```
function myFunc() {
    return false;
}

if(!(myVar = myFunc())) {
    console.log('true');
}
```

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/jLHpw/)

Answer (score 2):

It works in JS too:

```
var foo = null;

if ( foo = 1 ){
 // some code
}

alert (foo);  // 1
```

Or assignment even with a function:

```
var foo = null;

function getFoo(){
    return 1;
}

if ( foo = getFoo() ){
 // some code
}

alert (foo); // 1
```

With negation, you need to add braces:

```
var foo = null;

function getFoo(){
    return 1;
}

if (! (foo = getFoo()) ){
 // some code
}

alert (foo); // 1
```

In the last case, it is important to wrap assignment statement in parenthesis because `!` is then used to check against the result of that.

Comment: Isn't the original problem coming from the ! operator ? You don't use it in your sample.

Comment: @Tibo: Updated that just in case :)

Answer (score 2):

This is the preferred method for me (in PHP), because it makes it absolutely clear that you didn't mean to use the `==` condition but made a mistake.

```
if ( ($my_epic_variable = my_epic_function()) !== NULL ){
    // my epic function returned false
    // my epic variable is false
    die( "false" );
}
```

In JavaScript I'd probably do:

```
function my_epic_function() {
    return 5;
}

var my_epic_variable;
if ( (my_epic_variable = my_epic_function()) !== null ){
    alert("we're in");
}​
```